# How to manipulate packet and write to pcap file using pcap4j

Tags: pcap, libpcap, packet-capture, packet-sniffers

I want to get through a `pcap` file and go to each packet. Then get IP Address and manipulate it. In the end, I'm going to write it into a new `pcap` file.

I use pcap4j version 1.6.4 and below is how I get the Source IP Address:

```
String fname = "FileName";
String dumpFile = "newFileName";
PcapHandle h = Pcaps.openOffline(fname);
PcapDumper dumper = h.dumpOpen(newFileName);
Packet p = null;
while ((p = h.getNextPacket()) != null) {
    IpV4Packet ip = p.get(IpV4Packet.class);
    Inet4Address srcAddr = ip.getHeader().getSrcAddr();
}
```

As I mentioned, I got the Source IP Address and now I don't know how to set the new Source IP Address and write it to NewFileName.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Packet objects in pcap4j are immutable. You can, however, create a new packet based on an existing one and then modify it, using a [Builder](https://kaitoy.github.io/pcap4j/javadoc/latest/en/org/pcap4j/packet/Packet.Builder.html).

In the following snippet, I'm creating a new modified packet (assuming replace() contains your logic of creating a new IP address):

```
        Packet.Builder builder = p.getBuilder();
        builder.get(IpV4Packet.Builder.class)
                .srcAddr(replace(srcAddr));

        Packet newPacket = builder.build();
```

You can then dump the created packet using:

```
        dumper.dump(newPacket);
```